# User is in docker group but can't access docker commands anymore without calling `newgrp docker` before

Tags: 18.04, permissions, docker, groups

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS as my Desktop system and I usually had the user in the `docker` group for being able running Docker commands.
It seems that something recently changed and now I can't call Docker commands anymore except I'm calling `$ newgrp docker` in the shell before (or using `sudo`).

**PS:** `groups` (without argument) returns only the username but `groups $USER` properly returns all groups included `docker`. Is that expected or could that be related?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the reason for that. I recently switched to lightdm and it seems to have a bug that is causing this. It's [bug 1781418](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418).

The solution is either to uninstall `libpam-kwallet4` or commenting out these lines in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` fixes the problem:

```
auth optional pam_kwallet.so
auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```